# Mongoose- a single statement to update a field after usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a function like this:

```
router.post('/deleteDP',jwtValid,function (req,res) {
user.findById({'_id':req.decoded.id},function (err,result) {
   if(err){res.send("1");}
   if(!result){res.send("2");}
   if(result){
       var key = result.dp.substr(49,result.dp.length);

       s3.deleteObject({  Bucket:'probablee-dp', Key:key}, function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err, err.stack);
               return res.send("3");
           }  // error
           else if(!data){return res.send("4");} // no object found
           else if(data){
               data.dp = "";
               result.save(function (err,done) {
                   if(err){return res.send("5"+err);}
                   else if(done){

                       return res.send("6");


                   }
               });

           }
       });
   }
});
});
```

I'm supposed to delete an s3 object, which requires dp (a string field of the user) and after deletion I have to update the dp field of the user to "". I cannot use update statement first because it will set the dp value to "", thus, won't be able to delete s3 object.

How do I do this using a single mongoose operation?

Comment: so, you can directly do `result.dp=""` after line `data.dp=""`  and next you do the `result.save(...)`, so that it will save the updated result doc , am i able to catch your point?

Comment: Hey, I looked into that ... But docs are not saving on result.save(), because of the validation in the schema, is there a way I can bypass this validation on the schema side...??.. Thanks for the suggestion btw.

Comment: great to know, but i dont think we can bypass those validation, you can try to make it set to `null` may be, instead of setting it to `""` i.e. empty string.